# Django: How to do calculations when multiple models are linked together using annotation

Tags: django

I have the following Django models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost_per_kg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty_in_kg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    #qty_in_kg quantity of preparation

class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    qty_in_kg_of_ing = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    #qty_in_kg_of_ing: qty of ingredient in kg required to make the qty_in_kg of recipe
```

I want to get the total cost for making the Recipe.

How to get a queryset of recipes with extra column containing the total cost.

Comment: Where is their a relation from `RecipeIngredients` to `Recipe`?

Comment: Furthermore the units do not make sense, since you measure the ingredients as `cost_per_kg`, but later you specify them in `qty_in_kg_rec`, so what is missing is the quantity of each ingredient.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to first forget about annotations here, how would you *algorithmically* solve this in Python/Django.

Comment: sorry i added Recipe to RecipeIngredients

Comment: i want to solve it only by annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can annotate it as follows:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

subs = Sum(F('recipeingredients__qty_in_kg_of_ing') *
           F('recipeingredients__ingredient__cost_per_kg'))

qs = Recipe.objects.annotate(
    cost=F('qty_in_kg') * subs
)
```

This then results in query like:

```
SELECT r.*, (r.qty_in_kg * SUM((ri.qty_in_kg_of_ing * i.cost_per_kg))) AS cost
FROM recipe AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN recipeingredients AS ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredient AS i ON ri.ingredient_id = i.id
GROUP BY r.id
```

In case there are no *ingredients* in a *recipe*, the `.cost` will be `None`, not zero. So you need to take this into account when further processing the data.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are missing a field in the `RecipeIngredient` model, since there is no connection between `Recipe` and `Ingredient` at the moment there would be no way to collect all of the ingredients for a given `Recipe`. Here are the updated models with a foreign key `recipe` in the `RecipeIngredient` to solve the issue.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost_per_kg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty_in_kg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    #qty_in_kg quantity of preparation

class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    qty_in_kg_rec = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    #qty_in_kg_rec: required to make qty_in_kg
```

The script you would need to run is the following:

```
cost = 0
# Loading recipe
recipe = Recipe.objects.get(name="recipe_name")
# Finding every connection between recipe and ingredients
connections = RecipeIngredients.objects.filter(recipe=recipe).all()
for rec_ing in connections:
    # Calculating every ingredient cost
    cost += rec_ing.ingrdient.cost_per_kg * rec_ing.qty_in_kg_rec
# Calculating cost of recipe
cost = cost * recipe.qty_in_kg
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. I have added Recipe to RecipeIngredients. ALso i want the  solution purely with annotations and not with python models. Because i have lot of recipes and each recipe will have atleast 20 ingredients. At a time i want to display 100 recipes and their total cost. 

If i use python models it takes more than 4 sec to show 30 recipes